# Unable to get the CMS Topic because of Insufficient Privileges

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, salesforce-cms

I have a component which will load data from CMS Topic to display. However my partner community user cannot see that component and when I use debug to check it I get this message:

```
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.-Class.ConnectApi.ManagedContent.getManagedContentByTopics: line 448, column 1
```

I have done this to try to fix it but it does not work:

1. Enabled API settings in Partner Profile
2. Give Partner User access to Apex Controller

How can I fixed this ? Do you have any suggestion ?

Here is my method

```
public static List<ConnectApi.ManagedContentVersion> getBanners(String contentType, String topic, Integer pageParam, Integer pageSize, String language) {
    List<String> contentIds = new List<String>();
    List<String> topicNames = new List<String>();  
    CustomSettings__c comInfor = CustomSettings__c.getInstance('portsite');      
    String communityId = comInfor.CommunityId__c;           
    //System.debug('Content Type:' + contentType);
    
    try{   
        if(topic != null && !String.isEmpty(topic)){
            topicNames = topic.split(',',-1);                 
        }
            
        for(Integer i=0;i<topicNames.size();i++){
            topicNames.set(i,topicNames.get(i).trim());
        }                       
        
        ConnectApi.ManagedContentVersionCollection contentCollection = null;

        if (topicNames.size() > 0){                
            System.debug('CommId:' + communityId);  //-- this return my community Id
            System.debug('topicNames:' + topicNames);  //-- This return my CMS topic
            System.debug('language:' + language);   //-- this return my user language
            System.debug('contentType:' + contentType);  //-- this return CMS content type
            contentCollection = ConnectApi.ManagedContent.getManagedContentByTopics(communityId, topicNames, 0, 25, language, contentType);          //---- ISSUE CAUSED IN THIS LINE      
        }

        return contentCollection.items;
    }
    catch(ConnectApi.ConnectApiException e){
        System.debug('Error Message : '+e);
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        List<ConnectApi.ManagedContentVersion> mcvList = new List<ConnectApi.ManagedContentVersion>();
        return mcvList;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.debug('B2B_CMSContentController --> getBanners:' + ex.getMessage() + ' at line ' + ex.getTypeName() + ' :stackTrace' + ex.getStackTraceString());
        List<ConnectApi.ManagedContentVersion> mcvList = new List<ConnectApi.ManagedContentVersion>();
        return mcvList; 
    }

}
```

And the issue was cause in this line

> contentCollection = ConnectApi.ManagedContent.getManagedContentByTopics(communityId, topicNames, 0, 25, language, contentType);

Comment: What is there on line 448, are trying to perform any DML there? Might be possible that you don't have an access to perform that. But I couldn't be sure unless I know what operation is being performed there. Can you add that with the relevant code snippet here?

Comment: @rahulgawale I have udpated the code in the question and line got issue I have mention in the question too. Do you have any suggestion ?